# Office 2010 installation program got broken, somehow

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-office-2010, installer

A couple of weeks ago I realized I lost my icons for Outlook and Word (Excel is still available). Instead the icons are only displayed with an "empty page" symbol. After a while a thought I'd get this fixed by running a repair on my Office 2010 Pro installation (on Win8.1 with updates up to May 15 installed).
To my dismay I found that starting the office installation from Control panel/Programs & Features silently aborts. So I dug out my installation CD and tried to run it - however this one also failed: After the initial "Please wait .." screen I faced a "program aborted, searching for a solution..." progress bar up which finally ended in a pop-up "Setup doesn't work any more" followed by an unspecific "... you will be informed when a solution is available ..." message.
So now I'm stuck with a buggy office installation with seemingly no option to neither repair nor uninstall it.
I'm still reluctant to reset my installation with a backup from 6 weeks ago.
I'm inclined to keep fingers crossed an continue, hoping that this problem will fix itself with a later Office update.
Or did anyone else ru into the same problem and find a solution?
TIA

Comment: Have you tried installing on v. 8.1 *without* the most recent Windows update?

Comment: you may try to use an free uninstaller program to 'clean up' the uninstallation.. you may try the free "revo uninstaller" (not promoting.. just sharing a tool that I used and works most at most of my case).

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik: good point - after checking I found 5 update packages (expanding to individual 53 office and 4 windows updates) installed since the last - suspected - good state, which was my backup by end of April. I'll try to undo some updates. However if one of them was the culprit that screwed my Office, what options would I have to avoid such a mandatory update in the long run...?

Comment: @p._phidot_: I'm not quite clear how a more sophisticated uninstaller would help. After all I don't really want to uninstall my Office, just fix it. Did you ever use Revo in such a case?

Comment: Since you have a valid license, a clean re-installation using the same product key, shouldn't be a problem. Just get the product key in hand before proceeding. | If you are not sure, you may reach the Microsoft help (via chat, online) to assist on checking it..

Comment: If the updates conflict with MS Office, I'd try an alternative free replacement, such as LibreOffice. Of course, in some environments, that's not an option.

Comment: @p._phidot_: I'm still reluctant to completely remove my Office installation - provided the uninstall works! - due to the various customizations that accumulated over the years, but I may have to go down that route eventually.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik: I do have Libre Office installed for special occasions, but unfortunatly a complete switchover from Office is not an option mainly due to my heavy use of Outlook.

Comment: Have you tried the free Thunderbird email app? Though I do realize, some office environments are by company *fiat*.

Comment: The 'reluctant' can by easily addressed by contacting the Microsoft support. ( : There're surely happy to assist. (ok.. I'm not promoting.. It's just I had good experience with them in my previous case. I hope it goes well for your too. ) | 'how a more sophisticated uninstaller would help' it cleanse (not just clean) the OS setup by removing not just leftover folders/files, but also removing all expired/leftover registry entry that suspiciously 'makes' the window feel 'heavy'/bugged. During use, choose the 'advanced' option instead of 'simple', then Opt to remove ALL folders & registry entry.